# Can I use a LIDAR in combination with a GPS?

Tags: lidar, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating a robot and I need a navigation system. I am using a Raspberry Pi in combination with a Adafruit DC & Stepper Motor HAT, and a Rhoeby Dynamics R2D LiDAR. My main difficulty is my robot is spherical and I can't have a constant LiDAR scan running. Is it possible to create a map with the LiDAR using hector maps, and then use a GPS to navigate through the previously created maps. Another question I have is, if it is possible to navigate through previously created map using GPS, would it be able to locate and avoid dynamic obstacles such as furniture, people, or just any kind of randomly placed objects. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227625/can-i-use-a-lidar-in-combination-with-a-gps?/) by [megisblind](https://answers.ros.org/users/26075/megisblind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can't sense your obstacles, you can't avoid them.

GPS is only accurate to a few meters outdoors, and GPS reception indoors is usually poor, so it isn't useful for indoor navigation at all.

You might want to look into using an IMU to sense the orientation of your lidar, and use that in conjunction with a mapping package like hector_slam which can handle a moving LIDAR on an IMU.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0